# How to choose a story board in Xcode 5.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm working from an empty project. When creating a new storyboard, how can choose the default/main storyboard? The old versions of Xcode had a drop down menu for this. The closest thing I have come across is a drop down menu for "Main interface" in the general tab of the project. But I don't think that is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open project
2. Navigate to project settings
3. Open Info tab
4. Check if you have **Main storyboard file base name** key in plist
5. Set value Main for this key.

The value is connected to your UIStoryboard file name that is in your project. So you can point concrete file that you want to use.

Also on the **General** tab you have drop down menu under **Deployment info** part that says **Main Interface**.